# Link JavaScript file with multies HTML files

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have 2 files HTML, one called Tickets.html and another BookTickets.html with on JavaScript file named JavaScript.js.

The point is I try to link this JavaScript file to both HTML file, and it somehow can call work for me because can still call each element, class, id of each HTML.
Also console it and it show perfectly fine.
But when I try to bring info or text of one to another it always appears as `undefined`

HTML tickets file

```html
<a href="../BookTickets/index.html">
    <div class="nation" onclick="changeInfor(this)">
        <img src="../Tickets/img/francejpg.jpg" alt="">
        <h2>France</h2>
        <p>Vietnam is located in the east of the Indochina
            peninsula, in Southeast Asia. Sharing a border
            with three countries, Vietnam borders China to
            the north, Laos and Cambodia to the west, and
            the East Sea to the east.</p>
        <span class="icon">
            <i class="ti-thumb-up"></i>
            <span>
                <i class="ti-heart"></i>
                <i class="ti-ticket"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</a>
```

HTML booktickets file

```html
<div id="infor">
    <h1 id="namePlace">Việt Nam</h1>
    <img id="imgPlace" src="../Tickets/img/vietnamjpg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

JavaScript JavaScript file

```js
function changeInfor(src){
    var link = src.firstElementChild.src;
    var placeName = src.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
    console.log(link);
    
    console.log(placeName);
    document.getElementById('imgPlace').src = link;
    document.getElementById('namePlace').innerHTML = placeName;
}
```

so here I want to change the booktickets's img src and its namePlace by the information I got from click in Tickets file

Comment: If I understand well, you have 2 html files, each have a link on the same js file with all your functions. And you want to pass data from 1 html to the other. Did I understand well or am I totally wrong?

Comment: yes, that the case

Comment: ok don't expect variable to pass like that! When loading the new html (with the same js), it's "new". If you want to pass variable content from one to the other, search localstorage. You will find lot of tutos to use it, and it's very easy to implement.